# HTTP Request/Response from a file and back

Tags: python, python-requests, httplib, urllib3

What is the best way to parse HTTP request/response from a file to some kind of standard python objects and later dump it to a file?

What are the standard HTTP Request/Response objects in python. I need some kind of wrapper as output, just like `requests.Response` or `httplib.HTTPResponse` and also for request and a way to parse a file and load data to these wrappers/objects.

I don't know if httplib.HTTPResponse is some basic/standard class for that and why there is no HTTPRequest class and moreover i don't know how to convert them from plain text files to objects and the other way around.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have some kind of http traffic dump in a file that you wish to "replay"? In that case, what is the file format?

Comment: plain text files. I want to load requests, modify them in scripts and dump again to txt files. same for responses.

Comment: OK, "plain text file". But ... one request per file? Requests/responses interleaved in the file? Are the "chuncked" data reassembled or not? How are stored response containing binary data (like JPEG images?) How are identified various clients to map the correct response with the correct request?

Comment: Thx for your comments :) answers: request per file, same for responses. mapping => file's name - it's sequential number and client stores pairs to display request and correct response. binary data => right now don't know, for now just text files are enough I will think about binaries later. chuncked => reassembled. It's the API I got and I have to integrate with it :( Really appreciate, thx!

Comment: It sounds like you might be better served with a straight parser.  The stuff from `httplib`, and really any other library like it, is primarily geared towards interacting in a transactional manner with traffic on the fly from a socket, not pulling static text files and parsing them.  They also are way thicker than you seem to need, given all the networking code.  You might be able to use them by opening the file and throwing it at the library as a file-like object in place of a socket, but it still seems like you'd have a better and easier time just working with a lightweight parser.